# Easiest way to know (programmatically) which resources folder is used based on screen density/size

Tags: android, android-resources

Is there a way to know exactly which layout (and other resources) are chosen by Android during **runtime** based on screen density and size when supporting multiple screens?

I need to know the folder's name.

**EDIT:**

I need to know the folder's name **programmatically**.

Comment: From code or just looking at the device and project structure and asking yourself: where did this device get such layout/drawable from?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I refine my question.

Comment: I think this might be best suitable to get folder name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19155853/490683

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're just doing this for debugging purposes, I'd recommend doing something like this: For each qualifier that you have a layout/drawable for, have a values folder with the same qualifier (e.g. if you have a layout-hdpi, also have a values-hdpi to match). Add a strings.xml for each of these folders, and define a string:

In `values-hdpi`:

```
<string name="folder_name">hdpi</string>
```

In `values-xhdpi`:

```
<string name="folder_name">xhdpi</string>
```

Then just resolve the string when you need it, and it will tell you which folder was selected.

Answer (score 6):

Imagine you have a structure like this:

```
res/
    drawable-mdpi/image.png
    drawable-hdpi/image.png
    drawable-xhdpi/image.png
    layout/main.xml
    layout-land/main.xml
    layout-xlarge/main.xml
    layout-sw600dp/main.xml
```

and you want to know, which layout is used.

One way would be to put a value in resources:

```
res/
    values-mdpi/strange_info.xml with:
        <string name="image_is_from_folder">drawable-mdpi</string>
    values-hdpi/strange_info.xml with:
        <string name="image_is_from_folder">drawable-hdpi</string>
    values-xhdpi/strange_info.xml with:
        <string name="image_is_from_folder">drawable-xhdpi</string>

    values/strange_info.xml with:
        <string name="main_is_from_folder">layout</string>
    values-land/strange_info.xml with:
        <string name="main_is_from_folder">layout-land</string>
    values-xlarge/strange_info.xml with:
        <string name="main_is_from_folder">layout-xlarge</string>
    values-sw600dp/strange_info.xml with:
        <string name="main_is_from_folder">layout-sw600dp</string>
```

In code you just do

```
String mainFolderName = context.getResources().getString(R.string.main_is_from_folder);
```

I have some doubts regarding -Xdpi qualifier, but it should work (not tested). Note that with the above structure you will get "drawable-hdpi" on ldpi devices for image.png.

Answer (score 6):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                    break;
                case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH:
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: This solution does not work always. On my Nexus 5X the densityDpi returned is 420, which is between DENSITY_XHIGH and DENSITY_XXHIGH.
I would recommend the solution provided by @kcoppock

Answer (score 0):

The layout is chosen based on how you program it. Same with the menu and values. The photos are based on the definition: HDPI = High definition, LDPI = Low definition ect.

Comment: Yes sure, I refine my question.