# How to handle different screen sizes

Tags: android, layout

im facing a problem with screen sizes on android. I already implemented different layouts using layout-normal, layout-large ... the problem is in layout-normal it has the coverage of 3.4 inches phones to 4.2 or more i refer to this doc

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

now im using a samsung galaxy ace with 3.5 inches everything work well, but not on my samsung s4 and the an emulator of 4.0 inches who shares the same layout. Please help me.

the probem is on layout-normal, there are severl phones who have differernt screen sizes will have diffrent output layout.

is theres a way to specify a layout for 5.1 inches, 4,0 inches ....

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem tells me that you are using layouts incorrectly. The layout needs to be able to fit itself inside an approximate screen size. That is what the "normal", "large", etc. screen size buckets are for. Your layout should not take up exactly "5.1" inches, because there are so many different screen sizes, that you would have to make an overwhelming number of layouts if you took this approach.

You simply need to use `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` with layout_weight on the contents, and you will be able to use the same layout with multiple slightly different screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

im not really sure if this is what you are looking for..
but you can check the screen size of the phone

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;
```

and set it

```
if(width == 480 || height == 800){
            //get resource here
 } else if (width < 480 || height < 800) {
       //get resource here
```

this is just an example hope it helps.

Comment: so ill layout on the code ? not creating separate folders for each?

Comment: nah.. you can check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157220/easiest-way-to-know-programmatically-which-resources-folder-is-used-based-on-s
the code i posted only gets the screen size, you can set where you want it to get if the width and height either small or large.

Comment: NoobMe is thereds a way to do it via xml ?

Comment: because i was thinking about the positions of the edittext, textview, can i do that via java codes ?